# Publish to queue in message broker

Tags: wso2

I have been working for 1 week on WSO2 solution, I work with Enterprise Integrator 6.4.0.

I ran WSO2 Enterprise Integrator and WSO2 message broker and I can access to management consoles.

On message broker console I created 2 queues:
- Queue1
- Queue2

On Enterprise Integrator console I created a proxy with this code in order to consume messages presents in queue1 and put them in queue2 :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
           name="PS_JMS_X502a"
           startOnLoad="true"
           statistics="disable"
           trace="disable"
           transports="jms,http,https">
       <target>
          <inSequence>
             <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
             <send>
                <endpoint>
                   <address uri="jms:/queue2?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=conf/jndi.properties&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/>
                </endpoint>
             </send>
          </inSequence>
          <outSequence>
             <send/>
          </outSequence>
       </target>
       <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">queue1</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
          <rules xmlns="">
             <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
             <default>text/xml</default>
          </rules>
       </parameter>
       <description/>
    </proxy>
```

It doesn’t work and I don’t know where is the problem … Thanks you very much for your replies.

Comment: Proxy consume messages but does not publish them in queue2

Comment: Looks okay. Did you uncomment the correct transport sender in the axis2.xml?